# current draw effects on battery life

Tags: power-supply

I have a dc voltage regulator 12 volts in 9 volts out. it is drawing 8 milliamps. the battery is 12 volt dc 7 amp hour. how long will this battery last at this load?

Comment: Battery's datasheet usually has discharge curves for several load currents.  Post a link to your battery's datasheet.

Comment: Which dc regulator are you using that draws 8mA unloaded? There are plenty that are better - maybe you mean the 9V load and regulator take 8mA?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that's an SLA, see a typical [Data Sheet](http://www.yuasabatteries.com/pdfs/NP_7_12_DataSheet.pdf). But that's for a good-quality battery.

See also [Calculating the Battery Runtime](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/calculating_the_battery_runtime)

At such a low current you should get close to the nominal capacity. So 7/0.008 = 875 hours or 36 days. Subtract some time for self-discharge depending on ambient temperature.

That assumes your 8 mA is what the regulator draws from the 12V side.